# Bootstrap tabs + Jquery Masonry

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, jquery-masonry

I've been banging my head against a lot of walls recently and I can't find any working answers (even with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749701/jquery-masonry-not-working-with-jquery-tabs) that I might not understand).

I'm using masonry on div(class="box") and I'm trying to put those divs into bootstrap tabs.

The problem is : the reload doesn't work well, leaving gap and acting like the last divs are not cleared.

I've tried this :

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
            $('#content').masonry( 'reload' );
        });
```

But it's of course not working. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a[data-toggle=tab]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $(window).trigger("resize");
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    $this = $('#content');
    $coloumn = $this.width() / 4;
    $this.masonry({ columnWidth: $coloumn, gutter: 0, itemSelector: '.content_block_row_wrap' });               
});
```

I fixed similar problem with a similar of this code.
Live demo: http://shop.theme.firmasite.com/premium-features/
Check its codes.