# Implemanting Jquery Tabs and subtabs

Tags: jquery-ui

I am implementing jquery tabs in my project. I am new to jquery. How can i get the tab change event to make a new ajax call? 
Also I want to implement sub-tabs in some tabs. The sub-tabs should only be visible when the respective parent tab is selected.

Please give a suitable solution. Any effort would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get the `select` or `activate` event for tabs, as:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui){
        // Do stuff here
    }
});
```

For sub-tabs, you may attach events at run-time. If the sub-tabs are static, you may use the approach mentioned above with sub-tabs too.

Check this SO question on [trapping tab select event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3641154/1654121).